# Is every oscillatory motion periodic in the absence of damping?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

Well, I asked this title question to my teacher, and he told me that yes, it is true. But I couldn't quite understand how is it possible?

He gave me an example of a simple pendulum and told that it is both periodic and oscillatory. But a pendulum may not return to its mean position every time in the same time interval, right?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple pendulum is periodic but a [double pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum) even without friction, is oscillatory but not periodic.

Comment: Just a side note, I wanted to ask if it is possible to derive the equations for a double pendulum without Lagrangian mechanics ? A simple yes or no will do.

Comment: yes, for example: http://www.phys.lsu.edu/faculty/gonzalez/Teaching/Phys7221/DoublePendulum.pdf

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question I think it's useful to introduce phase plot. At each point in time the pendulum has both a position and a velocity. If you plot the position on the x-axis and the velocity on the y-axis you get what's called a phase plot.

Here is an example of a pendulum with damping

[image]

You see that friction causes the velocity and amplitude to go to zero over time. Here is another plot without friction.

[image]

Important here is that if you start from a certain point the path is already pre determined. Consider a path where you end up in the point you started from. This means you are guaranteed to repeat the *exact* same path. This means that each cycle will also take the same amount of time. If this happens the motion is periodic. For a friction-less pendulum this happens so it is both oscillatory and periodic. When there is only a little friction the path won't end up where it started but it will come very close. So the period will be about the same.

Answer (score 1):

The period of a pendulum at large amplitudes is not the same as at small amplitudes, but in the absence of friction, it still has a fixed period.

Comment: So....? sorry, i didn't get your point